# How to get the full path to an executable which is invoked from one of the directories in %PATH%

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, cmd.exe, ms-dos

Let's say I have an executable that I can invoke in Cmd.exe regardless of what directory I'm in because the executable's directory resides in one of the directories specified in `%PATH%`.  So:

```
C:\Users\MyAccountName> Blah.exe
```

or:

```
C:\> Blah.exe
```

I'd like to know where exactly it resides, though, i.e. which of those directories specified in `%PATH%` it resides in.  How do I get that information without manually checking every one of those folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type the blow in the command prompt:

```
where blah.exe
```

The documentation of `where` is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where_1).

Path is ordered, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653472/whats-the-relative-order-with-which-windows-search-for-executable-files-in-path)

Comment: P.S. if it returns two results, i.e. if two executables of the same name reside in two separate folders in the path, how do I know which one it uses when I invoke the executable without its full path?

Comment: The first one wins.

Comment: Note, the linux command for this is `which` if you ever have the same question on that platform. https://linux.die.net/man/1/which